# Remove Linux and GRUB while keeping Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, grub

My situation: I had a Windows 7 laptop, then installed Astra Linux on a new 10-GB partition.

If I try to boot Windows, it asks for a name and password, but I'm not sure what name it expects me to enter.

Anyway, I don't need that Astra Linux anymore, so how do I remove it and get back to Windows-only and its standard loader?

It seems I can't access Windows Recovery but I can access Linux Recovery mode.

`bootrec \fixboot` returns '...does not contain a recognized file system bla-bla-bla'.

Comment: Is there a certian reason why you dont want to use the grub boot manager? Because if there is no reason then just keep the bootloader, set the defaut os to start windows and simply remove the linux partion.

Comment: Because I cant even access my Windows right now, it wants some kind of username and password (on a black screen, not like it usually happens in Windows).

Comment: Well... Is your windows system somehow encrypted? Bitlocker? TrueCrypt?

Comment: No it was because of linux loader

Answer (score 2):

Boot from Windows 7/8/8.1 DVD and start the repair console. To restore original
Windows bootloader type the following command:

```
> bootrec /fixmbr
```

That is it! Optionally you can also rebuild bootsector if it is corrupted:

```
> bootrec /fixboot
```

After that, Windows will boot as usual, and you can remove Linux partition and extend Windows partition on the gained disk space.

Comment: /fixmbr - succesfully, it removed grub but i saw 'Missing operating system' error. /fixboot doesnt work, it says that a file system is missing. Auto-solve boot problems doesn't work either.